# Is there a name for appending letters to shorten numbers?

Tags: numbers, naming-conventions

Converting 1000 to 1k and 1000000 to 1M etc.
Is there an official name and standard for this type of operation?

Comment: You might find an answer in http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notational standard is officially called a "metric prefix" or "SI prefix".

Detail regarding this standard can be found in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) Wikipedia page.